# node.js application suddenly loads CPU at 100% and hangs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have simple application on node.js running on linux virtual machine. It listens for tcp messages and sending them to the clients using socket.io library. And after some time of low CPU usage it suddenly starts to load CPU higher and higher until application hangs up. The script is simple and I can not understand what's wrong with it.

```
var net = require('net');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(socketPort);

net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.setEncoding("utf8");
    socket.on('data', function (dataStr) {
        console.log("TCP dataStr " + dataStr);
        var data = JSON.parse(dataStr);
        io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('publish', data);
    });
}).listen(tcpPort);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('subscribe', function (room) {
        console.log('subscribe room ' + room);
        if (Array.isArray(room)) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {
                console.log('subscribe join room ' + room[i]);
                socket.join(room[i]);
            }
        } else if (typeof room === 'string') {
            console.log('subscribe join room ' + room);
            socket.join(room);
        }
    });

    socket.on('unsubscribe', function (room) {
        console.log('unsubscribe room ' + room);

        if (Array.isArray(room)) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {
                console.log('unsubscribe leave room ' + room[i]);
                socket.leave(room[i]);
            }
        } else if (typeof room === 'string') {
            console.log('unsubscribe leave room ' + room);
            socket.leave(room);
        }

    });

});
```

Also with cluster module I tried to run multiple workers that communicate with clients. And every worker after some time hangs own CPU core at 100% with time difference in about a minute.

**UPD:** Client code (run in browser):

```
    socketObj = new function() {
        var that = this;
        that.socket;

        that.init = function(nodeServerUrl, rooms, onPublishFunc) {
            that.socket = io.connect(nodeServerUrl);
            that.socket.emit('subscribe', rooms);

            that.socket.on('publish', function(data) {
                        onPublishFunc(data);
            });
        };
        that.subscribe = function(room) {
            that.socket.emit('subscribe', room);
        };
        that.unsubscribe = function(room) {
            that.socket.emit('unsubscribe', room);
        };
    }

    ...

    try {
        socketObj.init('application url', ["room1", "room2"], nodeJsCallback);
    } catch(err) {
    }

    ...

    nodeJsCallback = function(jsonData) {
        //Only updates data on UI, no subscribing, unsubscribing, emitting etc.
        ...
    }
```

**UPD2:** I tried to reproduce the problem with synthetic tests on production machine and on my local Windows machine. I have done some stress testing:

1. Multiple client socket connections
2. Multiple static data downloads (socket.io script for browser)
3. Increased frequence of tcp updates.

After few hours of testing I failed to reproduce. But when it is running on production with real users, it is hanging up earlier or later.

I'm starting to think this is either environment or specific message problem. Probably next things I'll try are:

1. Update Node.js to current version
2. Try to log all data transfer and replay it later hoping hanging will reproduce

Comment: Are you using a RedisStore for the socket.io store?

Comment: That's the first version of script. In this case I'm not using Redis as storage and have 1 process. Second version is using socket.io with Redis, 1 process listening for tcp messages and forwarding to 2 proceses that communicates with client browsers. Second version is hanging as well.

Comment: Are your Node/socket.io versions up-to-date?

Comment: What shows up on the console?  100% CPU is usually a sign of a loop.

Comment: @robertklep It was up to date when it was istalled. As far as I can remember, Node.js is v0.10.5 and socket.io is 0.9.12. Tomorrow I'll try newest version of Nodejs.

Comment: @OldPro Console shows nothing special. Usual console.log messages about receiving data and subscribing on rooms. And socket.io debug data about connections, websocket writing and heartbeats.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that, messages are repeatedly getting broadcasted room-after-room, socket-after-socket, like a never-ending echo. Can you also post rest of the code (most likely the client code)?

Comment: @RDX Thank you, I'll consider and check your guess, but I hardly beleive that is the problem, I don't see any possibility of perpetual broadcasting. Attached server code - is complete initial version of apllication. Also I attached the client code as well. It is only establishing connection and listening for updates.

Comment: I cannot run the server as posted because socketPort and tcpPort are undefined.  The socket io examples do not include having io listening on one port, a server listening on another port, and the server passing data to the io.socket.  Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: I don't thought the port numbers are worth the attention. But if you say so - tcpPort = 3002, socketPort = 80. We have configured firewall that tcpPort is allowed only for local network and application listens tcpPort for updates from our external application. socketPort is allowed for external connections, and is used for clients connections - subscribing on updates and retreiving updates.

Comment: Is "room" getting out of control ?

Comment: @user1737909 What do you mean "out of control"? There is 2 rooms, I changed names to room1 and room2 for question, because their's real names irrelevant. External application is sending data for room1 and room2 only (also I checked this in log) and separately. Clients are subscribing on room1 and room2 only (actually, all of clients now subscribing on both rooms).

Comment: Problem is magically solved by updating node.js to v0.10.8

Comment: Sounds like it was a memory leak in Node.JS!

Comment: I hardly beleive it is a memory leak. Memory consumption was relatively low. It is rather some kind of locking problem. As application is single-threaded, it happens something that locks execution loop at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed Nodejs from version v0.10.4(Stable) to v0.11.2(Unstable). All woking good so far, consuming 1-2% CPU. Now we are testing on v0.10.8(Stable).

**UPD** On v0.10.8 application is stable too.

*Even though the problem dissapeared on v0.10.4(Stable), it is still very strange and discouraging.*